# What kind of progress bar is this and why does it disappear?

Tags: macos, progress-bar, osx-yosemite

I see this weird progress bar in AppStore on Yosemite, which keeps disappearing all the time. When you switch tabs, it is there for some seconds, then gone again.

[image: weird progress bar]

Out of interest, I tried to figure out, what kind of bar it is and why that is happening, but can't find anything similar on google images.

In IB there is only the NSProgressIndicator, looks different and cannot configure it to look like the AppStore bars, so I guess they are using sth else?

The disappearing effect is happening on all Yosemite devices I know .. saw it happen both in the Mac AppStore and in the XCode->Preferences->Downloads screens.

Not sure anymore about iOS, but thought I saw it there too.

Any idea what element it is and what the folks at apple might be doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's a bug in the App Store. If you refresh the page it'll appear again and then will disappear after a little while.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, but it's also in Xcode preferences, so more like a bug of the UI element. Is it a normal NSProgressIndicator or some other thing? I want to avoid running into that when I try my first osx app.

Comment: Don't worry about running into it AppStore looks like it's been built using a webview, instead of being native.  The `NSProgressIndicator` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, someone should maybe tell the apple guys ;) .. will leave the question open in case someone knows what it exactly is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moused over it with the [Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html), and it appears to be a Web view. So that progress bar is probably styled in HTML and CSS, and is not a native control.

Answer (score 0):

A download bar because you are downloading.

Comment: Hehe, got a link to the HIG or class reference? Or at least the class name?